# Unexpected clipping of axes values in Plot

Tags: plotting, graphics

In working through Andreas Lauschke's extremely informative lecture series, in his lecture (#8) on Rarer Probability he provides the following code (not strictly contiguous and modified slightly to facilitate export of the resultant graphics grid):

```
ndist = NormalDistribution[];

pdf = PDF[ndist, t];
```

...

```
 graphicsrow = GraphicsRow[{
 p1 = Plot[Evaluate[pdf], {t, -5, 5}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, -3 < x < 0], Filling -> Axis, 
 FillingStyle -> Yellow];
 p2 = Plot[Evaluate[pdf], {t, -5, 5}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, 0 < x < 3], Filling -> Axis, 
 FillingStyle -> Cyan];
 Show[p1, p2, PlotLabel -> "Yellow == Cyan"],
 p3 = Plot[
 Evaluate[1 - Integrate[pdf, {t, -Abs@x, Abs@x}]], {x, -5, 5}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, -3 < x < 0], Filling -> Axis, 
 FillingStyle -> Yellow];
 p4 = Plot[
 Evaluate[1 - Integrate[pdf, {t, -Abs@x, Abs@x}]], {x, -5, 5}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, 0 < x < 3], Filling -> Axis, 
 FillingStyle -> Cyan];
 Show[p3, p4, PlotLabel -> "Yellow == Cyan"]
 }, Frame -> All]
```

This works without errors and generates the requested graphicsgrid in 12.3.0, like it does in the earlier version used in the lecture.  However, there is one slight exception. In 12.3.0, the values of the x-axis are clipped with only about 3/4 of each number being displayed at the bottom of each plot as can be observed in the following exported graphic.

[image: Result from exporting graphicsrow as a .png file]

Does anyone have an explanation why this undesirable behavior occurs and how to fix it?

Comment: no problem on 12.3.1 on windows 10. screen shot  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdBwc.png)

Comment: On a Mac it works as expected with either v12.3 or v12.3.1

Comment: Add option: `Spacings -> {{0, 0}, {0, 20}` to `GraphicsRow` to see if it is responsive for your version. On v12.2.0 Win7 it works fine.

Comment: I should have mentioned I am running 12.3.0 on a Windows 11 64 bit platform.  Unfortunately, placing Spacings -> {{0, 0}, {0, 20}} (NB with "}}") made no material difference, whether placed before or after Frame->All option of GraphicsRow

Comment: Apologies; I failed to include the last brace as I was copy-pasting from the cell.

Comment: Works on MMA 12.3.0 on Windows 10

Comment: reproduced with MMA 12.3.0 on Win 10 64.  toy can add  `ImagePadding -> 10` to each plot it solves it.